# Amibroker - How to update data for all DB symbols?

Tags: c++, plugins, amibroker

I made my own plugin for IBKR. How can I force the data refresh for all symbols in DB?
I need fresh data before launching an analysis or other options who needs them.
I can update only the actives symbols with:

> PostMessage(g_hAmiBrokerWnd, WM_USER_STREAMING_UPDATE, 0, 0);

but I can't chose which symbol update and get all DB symbols.

Can I use "wParam" and "lParam" for it?

Is there any option in Amibroker to do this?

BR

Comment: I tried with:
SendMessage( g_hAmiBrokerWnd, WM_USER_STREAMING_UPDATE, (WPRAM) name, 0);
Where name is: char name[100] = "QQQ";
I wrote 0 in 4th param because I don't need/have real time.
but I only receive a "GetQuotesEx" with the active pszTicker, instead of "QQQ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amibroker doesn't let refresh a specific ticker. Just call scanner 2 times or select a ticker 2 times, 1 for downloading + 1 store data.

Your IB + Investing plugin are gread!

Good job!